# apache mod_rewrite rewrite_map

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

On a shared server its not usually easy to get a RewriteMap for yourself.
So if you choose place all you Rewrites in .htaccess, will it slow the Apache?
for example:

```
RewriteRule www.example.com/a www.example.com/index.php?key=123
RewriteRule www.example.com/b www.example.com/index.php?key=124
RewriteRule www.example.com/c www.example.com/index.php?key=125
RewriteRule www.example.com/d www.example.com/index.php?key=126
```

and i have 8000 plus such lines?

this idea Vs RewriteMap how do you compare two?
Any other way of achieving what i am trying to do in example?

Comment: If there is a possible pattern, you would be better off using that pattern.

Comment: I do not have a pattern. i have items saved in MySQL with keys.That are pulled out using those keys.and i want cleaner URL's